# Envio de Registros de uma nova View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvc, redmine

Criei uma nova action `knowledges` no meu controller `responsabilities` e criei uma view chamada `nested_knowledges`. Fiz com que a action , renderizasse esta view. Coloquei o seguinte codigo nesta view:

```
    <%= form_tag edit_responsability_path do -%>
            <% for @responsability in Responsability.find(:all)-%>
                <% for knowledge in Knowledge.find(:all) %>
                    <%= check_box_tag "responsability[knowledge_ids][]", knowledge.id, @responsability.knowledges.include?(knowledge)  %>
                    <%= knowledge.nome %>
                    <br/>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
<div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag l(:send) %>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Ele renderiza um relacionamento has_and_belongs_to_many entre as tabelas de Responsabilities e Knowledges.

Coloquei o form_tag, pois se eu criar o form_for ele exibe um erro . Porém quando clico no meu botão para enviar , os registros de Knowledges que aquela Responsability tem, ele diz que não há rota,como no erro abaixo:

```
Started POST "/responsabilities/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-03 12:00:24 -0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/responsabilities/1/edit"):
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

O que preciso fazer para conseguir enviar estes registros?

Answer (score 2):

Melhor você dividir essa pergunta, você tem varias dúvidas juntas em uma pergunta só.

Mas, respondendo o erro das Rotas

se você incluiu em seu **route.rb** a seguinte linha

```
resources :responsabilities
```

Você possui uma lista de rotas pre geradas, nesse caso você colocou o seguinte path em seu form_tag

```
edit_responsability_path
```

esse path não possui um método POST. vai gerar algo do tp /respo../{id}/edit

Caso você queira acessar o metodo update do controller, sugiro fazer

```
<%= form_tag responsability_path, method: :put do -%>
```

Ou caso você queira acessar essa rota com um post tem que colocar no routes.rb algo do tipo.

```
resources :responsabilities do
  member do
    post 'edit'
  end  
end
```

Comment: Obrigado @Felipe Bergamo. Implementei utilizando o :          `<%= form_tag responsability_path, method: :put do -%>`. Para os registros de `nested_knowledges` funcionou. Porém tenho mais 2 `nested_competences`e `nested_tools`. Quando marco um conhecimento ele atualiza, porém se eu marcar uma competencia ele desmarca o conhecimento. Pensei que poderia ser os parâmetros que coloquei no meu Controller, mas aparentemente não é ,porque quando estava no `_Form` da aplicação funcionava normalmente.